# Retrieve only one Listitem with CAML

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, jscript, csom, caml

I tried to Query a sharepoint list. It should only return the Listitem which has the fieldproperty in the URL:

```
var Reference= getParameterByName('FilterValue1'); //refers to the funcktion
 var queryString = "<View> <Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='RefText'/><Value Type='Text'>" + Reference+ "</Value></Eq></Where> </Query></View>";

//alert(Reference);

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

camlQuery.set_viewXml(queryString);
```

It gives me always every listitem of the list, does anyone know how the proper CAMLQuery would be?

Answer (score 0):

If you need only one item add row limit in your query:

```
<RowLimit>1</RowLimit>
```

if your problem in query, check `RefText` field type. Is it text or another type?